# How to display URL link different than page JPS page?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, url

I am not sure it this is possible at all. I see that in Facebook when you crate a business page you will get a link with page number, for example:

```
https://www.facebook.com/degendaUK/
```

I would like to know if it is possible to create a link like that without having an HTML or JSP page called "DegendaUK" for example.

In my code I have page

```
http://localhost:8080/offers/empresa?get_Business_ID=29-11-2017-03:39:22R7M5NZ8ZAL
```

The standard page is called "Empresa" and then I pass the ID so I can query the database.

Is there anyway that instead of my URL I would get

```
http://localhost:8080/offers/BUSINESS-NAME
```

without creating a JSP page for each business?

I am using Spring MVC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use Spring @Controller, @RequestMapping and @PathVariable annotations to do this.

```
@Controller
public class Controller
{
    @RequestMapping(value = "/offers/{id}")
    public String offer(@PathVariable String id, final Model model)
    {
        //pass the value from the url to your jsp-view, access it via ${id} from 
        //there
        model.add("id",id);  
        //render the page "empressa.jsp"
        return "empressa";
    }
}
```

Hint: You may need some  and  in your XML config to make those annotations work.
If your using spring-boot, this should be preconfigured already an work out of the box.

Don't forget to secure those things if they're not public things using spring-security :)

Comment: Thank you I will test it